# Quickest way to clone a GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, calendar, copy, clone

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an object, including a `GregorianCalendar` instance. I'm always wary of using `clone()` and it doesn't seem to have been overridden here, so I'm just doing the copy field by field. Ideally, there'd be a copy constructor, which I could use like so:

```
GregorianCalendar newCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(oldCalendar);
```

Unfortunately I can't find any such functionality in the API and am stuck trying to figure out which fields I need to get an exact copy. So, to make a copy of one of these calendars, how would you do it? Am I missing some simple shortcut here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar` has overridden `clone()` which is working, so use it. Furthermore, `Calendar` doesn't have a deep data hierarchy — its data are mainly `int`s.

To extend the answer, you can call `SerializationUtils.clone(…)` (from [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)) on any object which makes a deep copy, if the whole data hierarchy implements `Serializable`.

Comment: I wasn't quite clear on why I'm avoiding `clone()`. In this case I'm just following advice from Joshua Bloch on making defensive copies. Since clone() could conceivably be calling a subclass clone() method I could end up with a non-clean copy. A bit academic in my case, but that's why I was avoiding it.

Comment: as I said, the data in the Calendar isn't affected by this problem - all its data is primitive. And the clone method in `Calendar` works fine.

Comment: His point is that you could conceivably make a subclass that keeps a reference to the original calendar instance and keeps that reference around. If, say, all setters would set values in the original instance instead of the new one, your "deep" copy will now be compromised.

Comment: You could also just do something like this:  Calendar cal_copy = Calendar.getInstance(); cal_copy.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis());

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted `GregorianCalendar`.

```
GregorianCalendar.from(                     // Convert from modern object to legacy class object.
    myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime()   // Convert from legacy to modern.
)                                           // Returns a new `GregorianCalendar` object.
```

But better to stop using `GregorianCalendar` altogether, and just use `ZonedDateTime`.

## `ZonedDateTime`

The terrible `GregorianCalendar` class was years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

You can convert back and forth using new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
GregorianCalendar myGregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

To address your Question specifically, combine these two conversions to get another `GregorianCalendar` object.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the quickest line of code to copy a Calendar is:

```
GregorianCalendar newCalendar = (Calendar)(oldCalendar.clone());
```

Comment: Better to case to GregorianCalendar

    `GregorianCalendar newCalendar = (GregorianCalendar ) oldCalendar.clone();`

Answer (score -8):

Uh, `clone()` sucks.

Is it that hard? You only have to set 3 things, I believe, the time, the time zone, and the locale.  All those fields have getters and setters.  Make a quite utility method to return a copy?

Comment: I don't understand; since both Calendar and GregorianCalendar implement custom clone methods, why would it not be appropriate to use them?

Comment: Hardness fallacy. Good programmers are lazy.