# Java Calendar.add affecting other Calendar objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, calendar

I am trying to add consecutive Calendar days into an `ArrayList`. When I add one day into `ArrayList` and later use Calendar.add method to go to next day, then I don't know why the `ArrayList` is also automatically modified i.e. the original entry is added 1 day?
Below is my code that would explain the situation:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestingStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        ArrayList<Calendar> cals = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
        Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.setTime(sdf.parse("Mar 25"));

        cals.add(startDate);
        Calendar secondDate = startDate;
        secondDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Calendar thirdDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        thirdDate.setTime(sdf.parse("Mar 26"));

        if (cals.contains(thirdDate)) {
            System.out.println("It does contain");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, it does not contain");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not expecting 26 Mar in the `ArrayList`, but it does.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar secondDate = startDate;
secondDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

This line means that `secondDate` and `startDate` refer to the same object, so modifying one also modifies the other.

If you want a new `Calendar` instance that's one day later than the other, you'll need to clone the first instance and then modify the clone, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499113/quickest-way-to-clone-a-gregoriancalendar). For instance:

```
Calendar secondDate = (Calendar)startDate.clone();
secondDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks that works for me!
I'm still wondering why did the object in the Array changed as both startDate and secondDate were changed later after inserting into Array?

Comment: What was added to the ArrayList was a reference to the same object referenced by `startDate` and `secondDate`, not a copy of that object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference for more details.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* class `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 25 ).plusDays( 1 )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using the terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

Seems you only care about the date, not the time-of-day nor time zone. So use the `LocalDate` class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Add days.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalDate dayAfterTomorrow = tomorrow.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Collect in a list.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( 3 ) ;
dates.add( today ) ;
dates.add( tomorrow ) ;
dates.add( dayAfterTomorrow ) ;
```

Or use new `List.of` for a non-modifiable list.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = List.of( today , tomorrow , dayAfterTomorrow ) ;
```

If you want to start with a specific day, use the `LocalDate.of` factory methods.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) ;
```

Then proceed with your date math.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i ++ ) {
    list.add( localDate.plusDays( i ) ) ;
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).